# Bar Graph with Adaptive Captions

Tags: amcharts

I would like to have a graph in amCharts where the x-axis is the time and bars represent in different colors and heights representing events in time. Now I would like to have that zoom-able so that captions in the bars only appear if there is enough space to display them. 
In my example picture the caption is not displayed on the magenta bars:

[image: A picture says more then a 1000 words]:

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this with a date-based serial chart. You could try using a separate step line for each column with fillAlpha set to 1 or one step graph and use fillColorsField and set color in your data at a position where color should be changed. As for labels, it's more complicated - graph has hideLabelsCount property, but it will show/hide all labels once certain zoom level is reached. You could try employ labelFunction of a graph and usesome function which would set label to empty string, depending on zoom level.